# Split a single row of data (dat file) into multiple columns

Tags: linux

I want to split a row of data into multiple columns like

```
a.dat
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U
```

into

```
b.dat
A B C D E F G
H I J K L M N
O P Q R S T U
```

I have tried using the pr function

```
pr -ts" " --columns 7 --across a.dat > b.dat
```

But it doesn't work, b.dat is the same as a.dat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [`fold`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fold) for these thingies:

```
$ fold -w 14 file
A B C D E F G 
H I J K L M N 
O P Q R S T U
```

With `-w` you set the width you desire to have.

Although `xargs` is more useful if you want to split based on number of fields instead of characters:

```
$ xargs -n 7 < file
A B C D E F G
H I J K L M N
O P Q R S T U
```

Regarding your attempt in `pr`: I don't really know why it is not working, although from [some examples I see](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch21_15.htm) it doesn't look like the tool for such job.